# I can't find my error, in this Fortran code

Tags: fortran, gfortran

when I use the INTEGER in declaration in this code, I have no error with gfortran, but when I use REAL in declaration, I have this error:

> Error: Type mismatch in argument 'a' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(4)

here is my code:

```
Program workout
IMPLICIT none
REAL :: resultat

resultat = moyen(100,50)
WRITE(*,*) resultat

CONTAINS
  REAL FUNCTION moyen(a,b)
    IMPLICIT none
    REAL,INTENT(IN) :: a, b

    moyen = (a - b)/2
  END FUNCTION moyen

End Program workout
```

thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit, you are passing an `integer` argument to a function which expects a `real` argument.  You could change this line

```
resultat = moyen(100,50)
```

to

```
resultat = moyen(100.0,50.0)
```

In fact, as you can see, you are making the same mistake twice in one line, the compiler is just identifying the first occurrence.